# how can I fetch the Ids from one table to another using the DashboardController and js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

i've two tables;

exam_Marks table

```
{id, codeid, examMarks}
```

examCodes table

```
{id, codes, codeDesc}
```

am trying to fetch the id of codes from table examCodes and pass them to exam_marks table,
however I can't earn this and i don't know where the problem is.
can anyone please help or advice me to use another method

this is my app.js

```
$scope.examcodesList = function() {
    dataFactory.httpRequest(
        'dashboard/examcodeList',
        'POST',
        {},
        {"classes":$scope.form.codes}
    )
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.subje = data.subje;
    });
}
```

and this is my DashboardController.php

```
public function examcodesList($classes = ""){
    $examcodesList = array();

    if(!Input::has('classes')){
        return $examcodesList;
    }
    $classes = Input::get('classes');

    if(is_array($classes)){
        return examcodes::whereIn('id',$classes)->get()->toArray();
    }else{
        return examcodes::where('id',$classes)->get()->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggle to understand you. Are you trying to copy data from one table to another ot get data and return it to your laravel app?

Comment: @EddyTheDove i have table examCodes  with {id, codes, codeDesc} so i want to link "codes" from examCodes table with  codeId  in exam_Marks table.

Comment: Are you trying to join tables ?

Comment: yeah...somehow joining them

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Not sure that's what you actually want.

```
if(is_array($classes)){
    return examcodes::join('exam_Marks', 'exam_Marks.codeid', '=', 'examCodes.id')
    ->whereIn('id',$classes)
    ->get()->toArray();
}else{
    return examcodes::join('exam_Marks', 'exam_Marks.codeid', '=', 'examCodes.id')
    ->where('id',$classes)
    ->get()->toArray();
}
```

Comment: thanks man, but i had to this; if(is_array($classes)){
            return examcodes::whereIn('id',$classes)->get()->toArray();
        }else{
            return examcodes::where('id',$classes)->get()->toArray();
        } to return examcodes::all()->toArray();